# web based Powerbuilder / Filemaker-type RAD tools

Tags: mobile, web, nosql, rad, filemaker

As the title aready points out:

I'm looking for alternatives to classical web frameworks for one-off, data-driven applications that primarily serve administrative purposes. Other than using online spreadsheets I don't really see any.

Requirements:

- Custom forms & UI (graphical builder)
- Programmable logic / data bindings
- Table-based or schema-less
- API access would be ideal
- Web / hosted
- Mobile-friendly
- Modern (not a web-port of some centuries-old RAD tool)

What's your take on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [CrossUI](http://www.crossui.com), it's an alternatives solution to classical web frameworks, and it's mobile-feiendly.